# Jmeter performance testing on mobile devices

Tags: android, jmeter, performance-testing

I have done all the configuration in Jmeter and my Android device. For configuration , I have refereed the below link:-
http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/186249-load-test-mobile-apps-easily. 
The issues is, while performing the steps on the native application (On Android phone) I am not able to capture 'HTTPS' traffic in Jmeter. I also installed the Jmeter certificate on my Android phone. Please help me to resolved above problem.

Note: I am able to capture the HTTP request through Jmeter.

Answer (score 1):

It look like you "referred" the link not very attentively. It states:

> Note that Android supports only HTTP proxy. If your application uses an HTTPS connection, then you may use an additional application that performs with HTTPS proxing.

For instance it looks like [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en) application does

> Support HTTP / HTTPS / SOCKS4 / SOCKS5 proxy

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you time, I have tried with the above solution but it did not work for me.
Please suggest some other solution to resolve this problem.